# Build Talk [libjingle] from WebRTC source for Android

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I've the code checkeout from https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk I can't seem to find how to build native libraries for ARM (android).

I need these libraries in (jni/.so) in the Android example project: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk#talk%2Fexamples%2Fandroid

p.s. the README inside example project is outdated and talk/build/build_jar.sh is very vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [example](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/), i have tried it and work success fully.

Only need to make one change is the link provided in this example for gclient config command is older one. Follow your link gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Also make sure that you have oracle jdk-6, other version creates issues while following the steps to get the native code

Comment: How to add webrtc modules in build path in eclipse on windows 7

Comment: The webrtc project is present under /libjingle/trunk/talk/examples/android   . You can import this project in eclipse.

Comment: I want it for video broadcasting using webrtc.